# mongodb devel cannot be installed on macosx with homebrew

Tags: macos, mongodb

I tried to install mongodb development version with this command as per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/):

```
brew install mongodb --devel
```

But it fails with this message:

```
Error: No devel block is defined for mongodb
```

`brew install mongodb` works normally. I am using OSX El Capitan 10.11.2.

Comment: I also have the same probelm

Answer (score 5):

That didn't work because mongodb is  no longer on --devel branch.

This works:

```
brew install -v --fresh mongodb
```

Comment: This installed 3.2 for me, but the latest RC is 3.4.0-rc2